# Generate an executable for each .c file in a directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

My project directory looks like this:

```
/project
    Makefile
    /src
        main.c
        foo.c
        bar.c
    /exec
        main
        foo
        bar
```

I want that the Makefile genrates an executable file for every `.c` file in `/src` folder and put the executable in `/exec` folder.

It's my first time using Makefile, I tried the code below but it generates the exec files in the `/src` folder and I want them to be in `/exec` folder

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRC_DIR := src
EXEC_DIR := exec

SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

all: $(SRC_FILES:.c=)

.c:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(EXEC_DIR)/$@
```

Comment: isn't the gcc command to generate an executable : ``` gcc file.c -o file ```

Comment: @Fredrik The `-o` option is used to specify the [name of the primary output file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o).  It has nothing to do with the *type* of output generated.

Comment: @G.M you are correct, I confused the -o flag with -c :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the different paths into account.

One possible solution is this:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRC_DIR := src
EXEC_DIR := exec

SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

all: $(SRC_FILES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(EXEC_DIR)/%)

$(EXEC_DIR)/%: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

**Hints:**

You can use `make -n` to check which commands make *would* execute, but without actually executing them.

Also, its options `-p` (print data base) and `-d` (debug) are helpful to debug your Makefile.